# Why does the IPython interpreter freeze on OS X when started with --pylab=wx?

Tags: macos, matplotlib, wxpython, ipython

I have a python package that uses both wxPython and matplotlib.  To get non-blocking windows, I tried starting IPython like this:

```
# ipython --pylab=wx
```

When I do this, the IPython prompt appears and a wx icon appears in my OS X panel but the IPython command line freezes immediately (I have to CTRL-Z and kill the process to exit).  I get the same behavior if I start it using "`ipython --pylab`" with the matplotlib backend set to "WX" or "WXAgg" in my matplotlibrc file.

I can start IPython with

```
# ipython --pylab=osx
```

But when I run any command that creates a wx window, I get an error stating that the `wx.App` must be created first.  So to make it work, I have to start IPython in `osx` mode as above and then immediately type

```
In [1]: import wx

In [2]: app = wx.App()
```

I am seeing this on OS X 10.6 with wx 2.9.  I get the same behavior whether using Ipython + packages installed natively or via macports.  I do not see this behavior when running on RHEL 6.3 with wx 2.8.12.

How can I eliminate the need for this hack and get it started correctly?

Comment: are you using a 64bit python? I ran into similar problems using Enthought, and wxpython is not available for the 64 bit version. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/22961778-epd-for-mac-os-x-32-and-64-bit-versions

Comment: I am using 64-bit python.  I am able to get wx working, as described above.  I just don't understand why I need the hack I used or if there is a way around it.